# How does the CLR recognise a "Corrupt State Exception"?

Tags: exception, clr

**Background**

Our application calls a mixed mode assembly, which has a known bug in its unmanaged code which causes an AccessViolationException to be thrown.

Our goal was to catch the AV exception, wrap it, and throw a new exception which would be caught higher up the stack and logged, before we terminated the application.

**Problem**

Our code did not behave as we expected... the 'vanilla' exception we used to wrap the AV exception *behaved like it was a CSE* and was not caught by our top-level exception handlers. Instead, it bubbled up to the OS, which terminated the process. This only left a confusing log message in the Windows event log, indicating that an InvalidOperationException had somehow managed to bypass all of our exception handlers and kill the process.

Note, this behaviour is only exhibited if the AV exception is set as the inner-exception on the wrapper exception.

Here is an example:

```
    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        try
        {
            ProvokeAccessViolation();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            // We never get here!
            Console.WriteLine("Log exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [SecurityCritical]
    public static void ProvokeAccessViolation()
    {
        try
        {
            var ptr = new IntPtr(1);
            const bool someValue = true;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(someValue, ptr, true); // Will throw AccessViolationException
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught AV exception: " + ex);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrapping AV exception", ex);
        }
    }
```

My question is, how did the CLR know to treat the wrapper exception (InvalidOperationException in the example above) like it was a CSE?

Similarly, why if you simply throw a new AccessViolationException from managed code does it *not* behave like a CSE? (...I assume the same mechanics are in play in both cases)

UPDATE:
Further to Hans' answer, here's a screenshot showing the AV exception being thrown and caught: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
    catch (AccessViolationException ex)
```

You made a simple mistake, otherwise perhaps illustrative of the considerable hazards of catching CSEs.  The problem is that you also have to know which particular CSE to catch.  There is more than one of them.

And yes, this mishap *started* as an AVE in the operating system.  But didn't stay that way, the CLR has a special rule for AVEs that are triggered by accesses in the lower 64KB of memory.  It turns them into a `NullReferenceException`.  Which you didn't catch.  Fix:

```
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Hans - interesting info... But I don't get the same behaviour on my machine (e.g. it's definitely an AVE which gets thrown when calling Marshal.StructureToPtr()).

In the original example, I'm interested in why it doesn't catch the InvalidOperationException in RunTest(). The CLR does not present it to the catch block, because it thinks it is a CSE. If you add the HPCSE attribute to RunTest it will then swallow the InvalidOperationException, as designed.

Comment: No, it's definitely a NullReferenceException which gets thrown.  Just change it to `var ptr = new IntPtr(65536);` to get an AccessViolationException.

Comment: Not on my machine :0) ...I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate. Regardless though, the catch in ProvokeAccessViolation() could just be catch(Exception ex). My question is really why you then cannot catch the InvalidOperationException in RunTest()?

Comment: I cannot repro that, but didn't use the MSTest runner and used a console mode app instead.  Do make sure that the Thrown checkboxes are turned off in the Debug + Exceptions dialog.